# How to add a base/front slug/url to specific post types?

Tags: permalinks

I currently have:

> mywebsite.com/custom-post-type-1/postname
>
> mywebsite.com/custom-post-type-2/postname

I want to achieve:

> mywebsite.com/my-base-slug/custom-post-type-1/postname
>
> mywebsite.com/my-base-slug/custom-post-type-2/postname

I do not want `"my-base-slug"` to appear for anything other than those specified post-types.

Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the `slug` argument when you [register your post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

```
$args = array(
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'my-base-slug/custom-post-type-1' ),
    // your other args...
);
register_post_type( 'mycpt', $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using a plugin, just have a look at [Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) or [Permalinks Customizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalinks-customizer/).